# Need to change column name when data fetch in to table in php code

Tags: php

I want chane column name date in to Day  i change it to like this but it is error how i chane it to day when displaying data.

```
<tr>
    <td width=""  class="rounded" scope="col"><?php echo $row['date as day']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

This is normal code

```
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width=""  class="rounded" scope="col"><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: /tr><tr><td width="" class="rounded" scope="col"><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td></tr> this is the code without error

Comment: you need to change it in yor query

Comment: By day do you mean weekday? Can you give an example of a date (there are several possibilities)?

Comment: please post your code php to we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean echo the day of the week. You would use the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

If your date is a date/time, not a timestamp you would use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to make it a timestamp first.

```
<?php echo date("D", strtotime($row['date'])); ?>
```

Will output Wed if it's a Wednesday

```
<?php echo date("l", strtotime($row['date'])); ?>
```

Will output Wednesday if it's a Wednesday. That's a lower case L not a number 1.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT date as day FROM table;
```

and then :

```
<tr>
    <td width=""  class="rounded" scope="col"><?php echo $row["day"]; ?></td>
</tr>
```

HTH.